# Android SQLite - Cursor & ContentValues

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

Is there any way to GET the ContentValues object from the SQLite?

It's very useful, that we can insert ContentValues in DB, and it should be more useful to get the CV from there.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use the method [cursorRowToContentValues(Cursor cursor, ContentValues values)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#cursorRowToContentValues%28android.database.Cursor,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) of the [DatabaseUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html) class.

example

```
Cursor c = db.query(tableName, 
            tableColumn, 
            where, 
            whereArgs,
            groupBy,
            having,
            orderBy);

ArrayList<ContentValues> retVal = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();
ContentValues map;  
if(c.moveToFirst()) {       
   do {
        map = new ContentValues();
        DatabaseUtils.cursorRowToContentValues(c, map);                 
        retVal.add(map);
    } while(c.moveToNext());
}

c.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote my own version of the [`DatabaseUtils.cursorRowToContentValues`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/database/DatabaseUtils.java#L704) method that David-mu mentioned in order to avoid [a bug with parsing booleans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13095277/689161). It asks the `Cursor` to parse ints and floats based on the types in the SQL database, rather than parsing them when calling the methods in `ContentValues`.

```
public static ContentValues cursorRowToContentValues(Cursor cursor) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    String[] columns = cursor.getColumnNames();
    int length = columns.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        switch (cursor.getType(i)) {
            case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_NULL:
                values.putNull(columns[i]);
                break;
            case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER:
                values.put(columns[i], cursor.getLong(i));
                break;
            case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT:
                values.put(columns[i], cursor.getDouble(i));
                break;
            case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING:
                values.put(columns[i], cursor.getString(i));
                break;
            case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_BLOB:
                values.put(columns[i], cursor.getBlob(i));
                break;
        }
    }
    return values;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can go to [thenewboston](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6) there's a tut for SQLite(and using ContentValues) from 111-124 :D

Anyway, the one that he taught about ContentValues is in the [117th](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=6&number=117)

Good Luck :D

PS : But he also use a Cursor :)

Answer (score 1):

No. You have to do that with cursor and old good query. I'd be happy if query could return a array of CV objects.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you have to use the `Cursor`.