# Create Cursor from ContentValues[]

Tags: android, cursor

Is there any way to create cursor from ContentValues array?

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: I'm getting contentValues array from web and I need to return cursor

Comment: Maybe a Map will do? You will return a Map and others will be able to traverse your map using this Map's iterator. If you really need a Cursor, then, Cursor doesn't exist without a database, you may want to write down your values to a db first.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean getting ContentValue array of objects from the database and then feeding the cursor with that array...well, thats not possible.

Same question was asked here
[Android SQLite - Cursor & ContentValues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932420/android-sqlite-cursor-contentvalues/7932471#7932471)

Comment: I'm getting contentValues array from web and I need to retur cursor

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by transforming ContentValues to MatrixCursor

Comment: How? How did you do it?