# Android - Database with ContentValue with boolean bug?

Tags: android, sqlite, boolean

I created database table in my android app. I used this query:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, mybool BOOLEAN)
```

Than I added row to the table, that the value of `mybool` will be `true`.
I ran the sqlite3 command to see the value in the table, and I saw:

```
  _id    |    mybool
----------------------
   1     |      1
```

That is corret, the `true` value became to 1.

The strange thing is in the reading. I read the table like that:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM foo", null);
DatabaseUtils.cursorRowToContentValues(cursor, values);
```

Then I get strange result:

```
values.getAsBoolean("mybool"); // return false - WRONG
values.getAsInteger("mybool"); // return 1 = true - CORRECT
```

I use the code like that to get boolean value:

```
values.getAsInteger("mybool") != 0;
```

But it's strange.

Why I get always `false` in the `getAsBoolean` function? Is there any bug in the `ContentValues` class? Anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getAsBoolean` does not return a `boolean` but a `Boolean` wrapper object, which can be either `null`, `Boolean.FALSE`, or `Boolean.TRUE`.
If you can ensure that there aren't `NULL`s, use `values.getAsBoolean("mybool").booleanValue()` to get the actual value.

Answer (score 7):

*DatabaseUtils.cursorRowToContentValues()* stores everything as strings (except blobs). *ContentValues.getAsBoolean()* will attempt to convert the string to a boolean (using Boolean.valueOf()), but that only works if the string is equal to "true", not "1".

This looks like an Android bug to me.

Comment: I agree! I'm guessing you [reported it](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54600)...

Answer (score 1):

You've skipped some code here.

What's your proof that values.getAsBoolean("mybool") returns false? You have to return a Boolean. How are you checking it?

ContentValues.getAs returns a value if the key can be found, or null if it can't or if the value can't be converted. Be sure that you're doing a full test.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best solution for this problem, but this code below works for me:

```
Integer result = contentValues.getAsInteger(attributeName);
            if(result ==  null || result == 0) {
                parameter = false;
            } else {
                parameter = true;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get boolean result like below:

`boolean result = values.getAsInteger("mybool") == 1;`